# Chrome HTTP2 connection stall

Tags: spring, apache, google-chrome, network-programming

I'm currently having issue on our application, where user is complaining that the web application is not responding in a timely manner. Upon investigation, we found in Chrome network tab that the user's connection was stalled. We enabled chrome event log (chrome://net-export/), and found the following (a snippet, this one is of type URL_REQUEST):

```
t=11948997 [st=    2]          UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_READ  [dt=0]
                               --> current_position = 0
t=11948997 [st=    2]          HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                               --> delta = -16375
                               --> stream_id = 17
                               --> window_size = 49160
t=11948997 [st=    2]          UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_READ  [dt=0]
                               --> current_position = 16375
t=11948997 [st=    2]          HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                               --> delta = -16375
                               --> stream_id = 17
                               --> window_size = 32785
t=11948997 [st=    2]          UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_READ  [dt=0]
                               --> current_position = 32750
t=11948997 [st=    2]          HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                               --> delta = -16375
                               --> stream_id = 17
                               --> window_size = 16410
t=11948997 [st=    2]          UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_READ  [dt=0]
                               --> current_position = 49125
t=11948997 [st=    2]          HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                               --> delta = -16375
                               --> stream_id = 17
                               --> window_size = 35
t=11948997 [st=    2]          UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_READ  [dt=0]
                               --> current_position = 65500
t=11948997 [st=    2]          HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                               --> delta = -35
                               --> stream_id = 17
                               --> window_size = 0
t=11983965 [st=34970]          HTTP2_STREAM_ERROR
                               --> description = "Abandoned."
                               --> net_error = "ERR_HTTP2_SERVER_REFUSED_STREAM"
                               --> stream_id = 17
t=11983965 [st=34970]          HTTP_TRANSACTION_RESTART_AFTER_ERROR
                               --> net_error = -351 (ERR_HTTP2_SERVER_REFUSED_STREAM)
```

(see how there was a big jump, from st=2 to st=34970).
I then tried to find why there was an issue with this stream_id 17. Here is an interesting snippet - this one is of type HTTP2_SESSION:

```
t=11948997 [st= 4768]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                         --> delta = -16375
                         --> window_size = 2147467272
t=11948997 [st= 4768]    HTTP2_SESSION_SEND_DATA
                         --> fin = false
                         --> size = 16375
                         --> stream_id = 17
t=11948997 [st= 4768]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                         --> delta = -16375
                         --> window_size = 2147450897
t=11948997 [st= 4768]    HTTP2_SESSION_SEND_DATA
                         --> fin = false
                         --> size = 16375
                         --> stream_id = 17
t=11948997 [st= 4768]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                         --> delta = -16375
                         --> window_size = 2147434522
t=11948997 [st= 4768]    HTTP2_SESSION_SEND_DATA
                         --> fin = false
                         --> size = 16375
                         --> stream_id = 17
t=11948997 [st= 4768]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                         --> delta = -16375
                         --> window_size = 2147418147
t=11948997 [st= 4768]    HTTP2_SESSION_SEND_DATA
                         --> fin = false
                         --> size = 16375
                         --> stream_id = 17
t=11948997 [st= 4768]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                         --> delta = -35
                         --> window_size = 2147418112
t=11948997 [st= 4768]    HTTP2_SESSION_SEND_DATA
                         --> fin = false
                         --> size = 35
                         --> stream_id = 17
t=11948997 [st= 4768]    HTTP2_SESSION_STREAM_STALLED_BY_STREAM_SEND_WINDOW
                         --> stream_id = 17
t=11983965 [st=39736]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_GOAWAY
                         --> active_streams = 1
                         --> debug_data = "[7 bytes were stripped]"
                         --> error_code = "0 (NO_ERROR)"
                         --> last_accepted_stream_id = 15
                         --> unclaimed_streams = 0
t=11983965 [st=39736]    HTTP2_SESSION_CLOSE
                         --> description = "Finished going away"
                         --> net_error = 0 (?)
t=11983965 [st=39736]    HTTP2_SESSION_POOL_REMOVE_SESSION
```

and there was another clue (this last one is of type SOCKET):

```
t=11944230 [st=    7]      SSL_HANDSHAKE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED
                           --> bytes =
                             14 00 00 0C 9A 01 88 7D  25 7C 71 2D 22 DF 26 49   .  ....}%|q-".&I
                           --> type = 20
t=11944230 [st=    7]      SOCKET_BYTES_RECEIVED
                           --> byte_count = 66
t=11944230 [st=    7]      SSL_SOCKET_BYTES_RECEIVED
                           --> byte_count = 37
t=11944230 [st=    7]      SOCKET_BYTES_SENT
...
...
...
t=11948997 [st= 4774]      SSL_SOCKET_BYTES_SENT
                           --> byte_count = 16384
t=11948997 [st= 4774]      SSL_SOCKET_BYTES_SENT
                           --> byte_count = 44
t=11948998 [st= 4775]      SOCKET_BYTES_SENT
                           --> byte_count = 73
t=11983965 [st=39742]      SOCKET_BYTES_RECEIVED
                           --> byte_count = 84
t=11983965 [st=39742]      SSL_ALERT_RECEIVED
                           --> bytes =
                             01 00                                              . 
t=11983965 [st=39742]      SSL_SOCKET_BYTES_RECEIVED
                           --> byte_count = 24
t=11983965 [st=39742]      SOCKET_CLOSED
t=11983969 [st=39746]   -SOCKET_IN_USE
```

This is where I'm stuck. So far I know there are a few pointers:

- HTTP2_SESSION_STREAM_STALLED_BY_STREAM_SEND_WINDOW
- ERR_HTTP2_SERVER_REFUSED_STREAM

Our backend is running Spring Boot 2.7.4, and there is a apache 2 reverse proxy - currently running 2.4.53.  We have enabled HTTP2, and using MPM event module.
I've checked Spring Boot GC log - there isnt any GC event during that time, and also, the request already arrived quite late at the apache 2 level (as reporting in apache access log).  So at this point in time, i'm 90% certain that the issue is on the client side.

Is there any more debugging info that I can gather, to find out what is causing the latency?  e.g. what is net_error = -351 ?
One last thing - the web application is using standard javascript fetch api (i.e. window.fetch), to perform HTTP POST, GET, PUT, etc.

Thank you in advance - any pointer is greatly appreciated!